# What are the ways to programmatically generate Material Design color sets?

Tags: java, android, colors, material-design

I am trying to create a colour palette of Material Design that changing the lightness / luminosity by percentage with arbitrary color hex. When it comes to the implementation, I have found that there are some color hex I cannot generate and shows Color Unknown Exception. Would you please tell me what are the alternatives or technical precautions to generate this set of colours?

[image]
The following is my code

```
package com.example.dino.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by larrylo on 18/1/15.
 */

public  class ColorUtils {

    public Context context;

    public static float[]  colorToHsl(String hexColor) {
        int color = Color.parseColor(hexColor);
        float r = ((0x00ff0000 & color) >> 16) / 255.0F;
        float g = ((0x0000ff00 & color) >> 8) / 255.0F;
        float b = ((0x000000ff & color)) / 255.0F;
        float max = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b);
        float min = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b);
        float c = max - min;

        float hTemp = 0.0F;
        if (c == 0) {
            hTemp = 0;
        } else if (max == r) {
            hTemp = (float) (g - b) / c;
            if (hTemp < 0)
                hTemp += 6.0F;
        } else if (max == g) {
            hTemp = (float) (b - r) / c + 2.0F;
        } else if (max == b) {
            hTemp = (float) (r - g) / c + 4.0F;
        }
        float h = 60.0F * hTemp;

        float l = (max + min) * 0.5F;

        float s;
        if (c == 0) {
            s = 0.0F;
        } else {
            s = c / (1 - Math.abs(2.0F * l - 1.0F));
        }

        float []  hsl  = {h , s , l } ;
        return hsl;
    }



    public static String hslToColor(int alpha, float hue, float saturation, float lightness) {
        float hh = hue;
        float ss = saturation;
        float ll = lightness;
        float h, s, v;
        h = hh;
        ll *= 2;
        ss *= (ll <= 1) ? Ll : 2 - ll;
        v = (ll + ss) / 2;
        s = ((ll + ss) != 0) ? (2 * ss) / (ll + ss) : 0;
        int resultColorInt =  Color.HSVToColor(alpha, new float[] { h, s, v });
        return Integer.toHexString(resultColorInt).toUpperCase();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> returnMaterialDesignColorSet (String colorHex){
        ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        float [] baseColorHSL = colorToHsl(colorHex);
        double randomMid = randomWithRange(0.48 , 0.52);
        String baseColor = hslToColor(1 ,baseColorHSL[0] , baseColorHSL[1] , (float)0.5);
        resultList.add(baseColor);
        return resultList;
    }

    public static double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
    {
        double range = Math.abs(max - min);
        return (Math.random() * range) + (min <= max ? Min : max);
    }

    public static int colorInt (String hex){
        return Color.parseColor(hex);
    }
}
```

Code for testing

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        double max = 0.52;
        double min = 0.48;
        double range = Math.abs(max - min);
        double value =  (Math.random() * range) + (min <= max ? Min : max);
        float result = (float)value;
        System.out.println(result);
        String test  = "#973f5c";
        String test2 = ColorUtils.returnMaterialDesignColorSet(test).get(0);
        int colorInt = ColorUtils.colorInt(test2);

        actionBar .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorInt));
```

Comment: Do you know what the problem is with the values being returned? My suspicion is that you are changing between hex, String, int and float values and some of the conversions are going wrong. I would stick to doing the adjustments on individual RGBA values then convert back to hex format stored as int (e.g. `int color = toHex(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));`).

Comment: Do u mean while changing the hue or luminosity ,generate different set of RGBA values first ?

Comment: I'd just have stuck to RGBA to get the effect. However, the principle is the same. The errors are likely to come from providing values that are of the incorrect format or out of range of the conversion when generating the colours. Can you show the trace of the error to identify the line where the error is coming from? I suspect it will be a line like `int resultColorInt =  Color.HSVToColor(alpha, new float[] { h, s, v });`. If you output each value to the console `Log.d("hue",Float.toString(h));`, I suspect that you will see incorrect values.

Comment: Try generating hex strings #ff1212.. Since odd digits represent major changes, you can decrease even digits for that gradient look.  so if ff0000 most red, fd0000 will be close to most red. just decrease even digits till they are zero and then decrement major digits.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these helpful images. Did you make them yourself or found it somewhere?

Comment: `returnMaterialDesignColorSet` returns only 1 element :( How can I return full palette?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original problem**

Your code has error working with color format.
Replace last line of `hslToColor()` like shown below and you'll make it run without errors:

```
public static String hslToColor(int alpha, float hue, float saturation, float lightness) {

    ...

    // !!! ERROR WAS ON THE LAST LINE:
    return String.format("#%08x", resultColorInt).toUpperCase();
}
```

I've tested it - **it works** - because it makes 2 additional things:

1) Formats value to have 8 digits
2) Adds "**#**" prefix

**Possible SECOND problem in your code**

The alpha value may have values from 0 (transparent) to 255 (opaque). If you want to have opaque image you should pass 255 (0xFF).
Now you pass `1` and *I think it's an error* - because it's almost transparent. 
So to have opaque color replace line

```
String baseColor = hslToColor(1 ,baseColorHSL[0] , baseColorHSL[1] , (float)0.5);
```

with

```
String baseColor = hslToColor(0xFF ,baseColorHSL[0] , baseColorHSL[1] , (float)0.5);
```

**Annex**
If one needs to get a set of colors -  a bit of creativity should be applied.
To create a tint palette you have to change in a loop **a)** saturation or **b)** lightness or **c)** both of them.
Here is an implementation example that returns palette based on lightness change from 0.4 to 0.6 (non inclusive) in 10 steps.
"Experimental" means that you should find values for yourself.

```
public static ArrayList<String> returnMaterialDesignColorSet(String baseColorHex, int colorCount) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
     float [] baseColorHSL = colorToHsl(baseColorHex);

    float lght=0.4;// initial lightness value (experimental)
    float lStep=(0.6 - lght) / colorCount; // step to go up to 0.6 lightness (experimental)
    for (int i = 0; i < colorCount; i++) {
         String baseColor = hslToColor(1 ,baseColorHSL[0] , baseColorHSL[1] , lght);
         resultList.add(baseColor);
         lght += lStep;
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: Well done, son! Your country is proud of you! It's awesome, together with original question. But, `returnMaterialDesignColorSet` returns only 1 element :( How can I return full palette?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, but... are these Material colors? Why did you said that? I extracted from material spec page all color codes, created an excel file whit these and add filter for satisfy my nees. I am pretty sure that those are "original" material colors. But yours? Yes, ok, it allows to generate colors in a range. But Material colors?

Comment: If you want to find out how Google generated material colors you should do a little investigation: convert chosen palette to HSL and see how Google changes saturation and/or lightness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following lines:

```
int resultColorInt =  Color.HSVToColor(alpha, new float[] { h, s, v });
return Integer.toHexString(resultColorInt).toUpperCase();
```

When alpha value is less than 16 (0xF0), it will occupy only one char in the string:

```
// 1-char alpha
int resultColorInt =  Color.HSVToColor(1, new float[]{340, 0.7f, 0.5f});
String result = Integer.toHexString(resultColorInt).toUpperCase();
// result == "1802644" - 7 chars, which is invalid color format
```

You need to compensate 1-char or 0-char alphas (in range 0-15) by appending 0 at the beginning of the resulting string:

```
// not the best code, but works
while (result.length() < 8) {
    result = "0" + result;
}

// don't forget # to make it a legal color
result = "#" + result;
return result;
```

However, the best thing would be to avoid strings altogether. Use ints instead - they contain the same data with better performance. For your convenience, in debugger you can change ints to be displayed in HEX, instead of DEC (in Android Studio: right click in Variables view, View as -> HEX).