# Variants of hex colors

Tags: android

I am trying to get variants of a hex colour, given its percentage of variant. For example my hex colour is #FFFFFF , where i need to find five variants 95% is #F2F2F2 , 85% is #D9D9D9 , 75% is #BFBFBF , 65% is #A6A6A6 , 50% is #808080. How can i calculate this programatically? How can i increase or decrease the brightness of a color code depending on some percent?

Code snippet tried:

```
void brighten(int color, float fraction) {

    int r = Color.red(color);
    int g = Color.green(color);
    int b = Color.blue(color);

    r += (int) (fraction * (255 - r));
    g += (int) (fraction * (255 - g));
    b += (int) (fraction * (255 - b));

    if (r < 0) {
        r = 0;
    }
    if (r > 255) {
        r = 255;
    }
    if (g < 0) {
        g = 0;
    }
    if (g > 255) {
        g = 255;
    }
    if (b < 0) {
        b = 0;
    }
    if (b > 255) {
        b = 255;
    }

    String resultColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b) & 0x00ffffff);    

}
```

This works for colors to some extend as it only darkens with given percentage. But it doesn't works to all color uniformally (example : #000000).

Comment: Possible your answer is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012185/what-are-the-ways-to-programmatically-generate-material-design-color-sets

Comment: You can use a color matrix

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below method to solve your problem.**

```
// Function Calling
brighten(0x00FFFFFF, 65); //Para 1 : color code  // Para 2 : percentage of color code that what you want.

void brighten(int color, int persontage) {

            double r = Color.red(color);
            double g = Color.green(color);
            double b = Color.blue(color);

            r = Math.ceil((r*persontage) / 100);
            g = Math.ceil((g*persontage) / 100);
            b = Math.ceil((b*persontage) / 100);


            String resultColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b) & 0x00ffffff);
            Log.i(TAG, "brighten: resultColor : " + resultColor);
        }
```

Comment: @D Prince The same doesn't works to all color uniformally (example : #000000)